# Speech Recognition with Telephone

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, tapi

I need to detect the user voice when they pick-up the reciever on the other 
end. Because Modems usually start playing files (playback terminal) when the 
first ring goes there. So I planned to use speech recognition when they say 
"hello", it can start play the file until wait for playing file. Or even any 
noise interference it can start speak. I have a code that can recognize the wav file but i'm struggling to add with my telephone application . I'm using Tapi Manager from C4F for making the calls. The calling is perfect but how shall I add it with my application???

Any link or help that will give or guide how can we integrate the 2 applications????

Comment: Do you actually need to know what the user said, or do you want to detect speech-like audio?

Comment: I need to know whether they picked up the call or the number is busy. I have almost done that i found few common words that my engine was detecting when ring was going and when they pick up or if the audio is being played for number busy but now the problem is that it works as a stand alone application if i integrate this with my application the Speech Hypothesis event is not getting raised and hence nothing is recognized . I don't know why this is happening. engine works great as alone but not working with the application all other event's are raised except this. Any idea???

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have better luck listening for a busy signal or waiting until ringing stops.  What if they answer in another language?  What if they don't say anything?  What if it's an answering machine?

Comment: ...or if they say "hi" or "hey"... (probably more common on an answering machine than a real person talking though)